# What's the idiomatic phrase for the following situation (cut off vs. hang up)?

Tags: idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

We have a group conversation (of 3 friends) on phone, after some time one of us was '**cut off**' / '**hanged up**' of the conversation. Which of them is more intended for unexpected or non-wished such ending of conversation?

For example,  when he calls again to join our conversation, I can tell him:

> We didn't notice that you got **cut off** the call / **hanged up**.

He may response:

> Yes, I'm sorry that the call was **cut off** / **hanged up**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for for when a disconnection is not initiated by anyone on the call is

> **cut off**
>   My phone lost signal and I got **[cut off](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cut-off#cut-off__20)**.

As opposed to

> When the call was finished, I **[hung up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hang-up_1#hang-up_1__1)** and got back to my other work.

Where the disconnection is intentional.